# How do I create two dropdown menus with different properties using the same .dropit css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, drop-down-menu

**HTML:** I am using the classes 'menu' and 'settings1' for my two dropdown menus.

**Dropdown elements 1:** Menu

```
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="btn">+ Add</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Note</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Image</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

**Dropdown elements 2:** Settings1

```
<ul class="settings1">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

**JS calls for each:** I reference both the classes (menu and settings1) into my dropit.css file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".menu").dropit();
 $( "#menu" ).click(function() {
     $("#left-nav").toggleClass("open", 200);
 });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".settings1").dropit();
 $( "#settings1" ).click(function() {
     $("#left-nav").toggleClass("open", 200);
 });

</script>
```

In my .dropit CSS file, I have started the formation of the dropdown but how do I distinctively call either the settings1 or the menu class so I can have different properties for each?

```
.dropit {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 15px 0 0;
float: right;
display: inline;
}
.dropit .dropit-trigger { position: relative; }
.dropit .dropit-submenu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;

z-index: 1000;
display: none;
min-width: 100px;
list-style: none;
padding: 20px;
margin: 20px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly then just apply the CSS directly to `.menu` and `.settings1`.